# Strange error message with Phar

Tags: php, phar

Using `phar` to create `tar.gz` archive returns a strange error, the following is the error message:

> exception 'BadMethodCallException' with message 'Unable to add newly
>   converted phar
>   "c:/www/dimg/uploads/7e6d3a5e39e43d1351e7069517f11250.tar.gz" to the
>   list of phars, a phar with that name already exists' in
>   c:\www\dimg\upload.php:163 Stack trace:
>
> 0 c:\www\dimg\upload.php(163): PharData->compress(4096)
>
> 1 {main}

The snippet to produce Phar archives am using:

```
$dir_id        = md5(microtime() . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
$upload_dir    = 'uploads/' . $dir_id;
mkdir($upload_dir, 777);

try {
    $a = new PharData($upload_dir . '.tar.gz');
    $a->buildFromDirectory($upload_dir);
    $a->compress(Phar::GZ);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $error = true;
    $err_msg .= '<li>Exception : ' . $e . '</li>';
}
```

I tried to empty uploads directory but the same error is produced each time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using

```
$a = new PharData($upload_dir . '.tar.gz');
```

Use:

```
$a = new PharData($upload_dir . '.tar');
```

Actually compress generates two .tar and then tar.gz. Since you have specified .tar.gz as the initial output, it cannot overwrite it with the same file type.

Comment: That is what I was missing.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is that you are trying to build the directory that the `tar.gz` is being sent to. In other words, you are telling it to build to a particular directory, and then telling it to build that directory.

All you should need to do is build the `tar.gz` in another directory than the one you are trying to compress.

Comment: I thought so in the beginning, but creating the archive in different directory didn't solve the problem.

Comment: What was the different folder that you tried to create it in?

Comment: Current directory like this: `$a = new PharData('new-archive.tar.gz');`.